# position:fixed does not work on android

Tags: html, css, navigation, css-position

I am building a responsive website using a modified 960 grid:

```
@media only screen and 
(min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 959px){

.container_12{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 720px;
}
}
```

and a navigation bar that uses position:fixed to lock itself to the top of the page.

```
.nav-band{
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image:url('../img/trans_black.png');
    padding: 2px;
}
```

This works fine in most cases, but it breaks on my android tablet.  The page loads and works fine, but when I rotate the tablet (which changes all tags with .container_12 from width:720px to width:480px) the nav bar either disappears or gets locked in an odd place, half way down the page.  How can I fix this?  The site also has an image that appears behind the nav bar within .header-band:

```
.header-band{
    background-image:url('../img/header_band3.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:top;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #050505;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

<div class='pageband nav-band'>
<ul class='horizontal-list'>
<li class='nav-item active'>
<a href="http://...">Home</a>
</li>
...
</ul>
</div>
<div class='pageband header-band'>&nbsp;</div>
<div class='pageband core-band'>
<div class='pageband logo-band '>
<div class='container_12'>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `position: fixed` but do not actually position the element. Add `top: 0px` and `left: 0px` to your navigation bar css to make sure it is positioned at the top of the screen.

```
.nav-band{
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image:url('../img/trans_black.png');
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: adding top:0px and left:0px; fixed the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this codes:

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape){
   .nav-band {
      // rest of code
   }
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait){
   .nav-band {
      // rest of code
   }
}
```

This will target your device orientation and "reset" your code.

Comment: This code works fine if I rotate my android before I scroll down the page, but if I am viewing content "below the fold", the nav bar gets locked in a position lower that the top of the page.  It could be locked in the middle of the view, or below the view making it completely unseen (I assume this is what's happening.  I cant see the nav bar.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help on this frustrating issue.

`position: fixed;` initially failed on my android and desktop devices.
*removing* `position: relative`; from the `fixed` element container fixed the problem on the desktop but not the android (Galaxy Note 5)
Adding 
`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the element did not work for android either but did cause some interesting flickering and position changes...
adding `display: block;` to the element's container fixed the positioning on the android and it still works on the desktop.

Good stuff looks like this
css:

```
body {
  background-image: url("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  display: block;
  height: 200vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;  
  width: 100vh;  
} 

#fixed-red-box {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 6%; 
  right: 4%; 
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
  height: 5vh; 
  width: 10vw; 
  border: 1vw solid red; 
  z-index: 300;
  }  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-
       scale=1"/>version=5.1"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fixed-red-box"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

took a month to find this fix.  Not a coder but do some coding hope this may help someone else with this problem.